# Create a vNIC w/o VLAN ID using HP NCU

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp, vlan

On a physical server hardware System x3550 M3 with NIC teaming configured, is that possible to create a vNIC without VLAN ID assigning to it in HP Network Configuration Utility?

Perhaps, this can be achieved thru CLI?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you show is to add a VLAN which would require picking the tag.  Are you asking how to add a Team without assigning it to a particular VLAN?  Why wouldn't you just set the Default/Native VLAN id?

Comment: Not a team without assigning it to a particular VLAN, but vNIC with no VLAN ID under already existing team?

Comment: You can't do that as far as I'm aware.  You'll need to either just add it to the default/native VLAN id (in your case 2714) or specify a VLAN Id for the VLAN it should be a part of based on the switch's VLAN tags.